# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los códigos de las funciones de Java?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo saber el código "oculto" del método `indexOf()`? He buscado en la API de Java pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: En IntelliJ o Eclipse (posiblemente otros), al hacer `Ctrl+click` sobre la función que quieres ver, la IDE descarga los fuentes y te muestra su código fuente.

Comment: @rnd eso depende. Usualmente funciona cuando trabajas con Maven o Gradle. Pero el IDE de todas maneras no descarga mágicamente las fuentes de Java

Comment: En 99% de las veces  no deberías plantearte esta necesidad, la documentación del método y de la clase (es decir, el "contrato") debería bastarte.

Comment: @leonbloy es útil cuando quieres aprender cómo en Java se implementan patrones de diseño. [Esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/1065197) lo explica muy bien.

Answer (score 7):

Instala el JDK de java si no lo tienes, ahí en la carpeta del JDK hay un archivo llamado **src.zip**, puedes extraerlo y ver todos los codigos fuentes.

Para saber en que parte está el método, al completar código en tu IDE, en la información del método te sale el "directorio" en el que está.

Por ejemplo **.indexOf()** se encuentra en `java.​lang.​String`
que es la ruta que deberás seguir para llegar a la declaración de la función y su implementación. O también si presionas la tecla <kbd>CTRL</kbd> y das click sobre tipo de variable *String* te va a llevar hasta el código fuente y ahí buscas la declaración del metodo.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando instalas el JDK, en la ruta de instalación existe una carpeta llamada src.zip. Allí encontrarás las fuentes de las principales clases de Java, reconocidas por los paquetes `java.` y `javax.` como fuentes de swing, awt, entre otros. Puedes descomprimir estas fuentes o utilizar tu IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) para que navegues por las fuentes con mayor facilidad.

Otra forma de ver las fuentes de Java es accediendo al repositorio en línea en mercurial con la siguiente url: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes. Estas fuentes apuntan a la versión 8 del JDK. Puedes navegar entre esos repositorios y acceder a las fuentes de la versión 9.

Answer (score 2):

Eso no forma parte de la definición del lenguaje Java, sino que es parte de la particular implementación, puede variar entre implementaciones (distintos fabricantes, o versiones), y normalmente no debería importarte.
Si realmente lo necesitas, puedes bajarte el código fuente de la mayoría de las JRE, y algunas se encuentran online. [Por ejemplo](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.indexOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: la vieja y querida encapsulación...